# Return type from valueForKeyPath:?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, kvc

This is probably pilot error on my part, but I am  a little confused why this does not return an int (as thats the type of the property identified by the key path). Does valueForKeyPath: return an object instead, can anyone explain.

```
// Simple Object
@interface Hopper : NSObject
@property(nonatomic, assign) int mass;
@end

// Test
Hopper *hopper = [[Hopper alloc] init];
[hopper setMass:67];
NSLog(@"HOPPER: %d", [hopper valueForKeyPath:@"mass"]);
```

.

```
WARNING: Conversion specifies type 'int' but the argument has type 'id'
```

Comment: Hopper *hopper = [[alloc] init]; should be Hopper *hopper = [[ Hopper alloc] init];

Comment: Thanks meccan, my error I should have pasted it from Xcode, rather than just typing it a fresh here. I have updated the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it returns an objc object:

```
- (id)valueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath;
```

Details for automatic conversions from non-objc objects to objc objects (e.g. `NSNumber` and `NSValue`) is covered in [Accessor Search Patterns for Simple Attributes](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/SearchImplementation.html).

Therefore, you would use the objc object format specifier `%@`:

```
NSLog(@"HOPPER: %@", [hopper valueForKeyPath:@"mass"]);
```

Answer (score 2):

valueForKeyPath returns an object.  int and char types are not objects.  Access the property via the . operator or similar.

```
NSLog(@"HOPPER: %d", [hopper mass]);

NSLog(@"HOPPER: %d", hopper.mass);
```

*Edit: Didn't fully read example code, updated answer*

Comment: Thank you, its not at all clear as the docs say "Return Value
The value for the derived property identified by keyPath." which to the un-initated could be a none object.

Comment: it does say - (id) just spotted that.

Comment: Must learn to read more carefully before posting an answer.  Also see @meccan's comment on your question.

Comment: Thanks for the update, the only reason I am doing it this way is I am testing out KVO and I was confused by what I was getting from -(void)observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:

Comment: NP Diziet, your answer was very helpful, thanks for taking the time.